# Multiple canvas using skiasharp in one view

Tags: xamarin, skiasharp

I am trying to use multiple canvas in a view, however only the second canvas is being displayed in the view. Is there a different way to show multiple canvas?

```
<ContentView>
    <StackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="Canvas" PaintSurface="Draw" EnableTouchEvents="True" Touch="OnTouch" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="CanvasBody" PaintSurface="CanvasBody_PaintSurface" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></skia:SKCanvasView>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: You are setting the horizontal and vertical options to FillAndExpand to both cases. Try to set a HeightRequest, to see if both of them are showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Grid Row and Column definition. The issue you are having is the second canvas is on top of the other canvas. After assigning row and column definition you have them separated.